# Can not open new files on SD with NodeMCU FATFS module

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm using the NodeMCU environment to write a Lua script for the ESP8266. It uses the FATFS module to create several files with the following pattern:

LOG_xxxxyymmdd_hhmmss.txt, where xxxx: #file(incremental), and the rest is a timestamp.

I was running a test, creating one file, filling it with a small amount of data (~200 bytes), closing it, and repeating this for X times. After the first hour had passed, the files stopped being created. Here is the list of files created successfully:

```
<script src="https://pastebin.com/embed_js/0xn3MBQt"></script>
```

And here are some filenames it couldn't create:

LOG_0193000101_005909.txt

LOG_0194000101_005908.txt

LOG_0000000000_000000.txt

LOG.txt

I'm really troubled by this. Is there some kind of filename size limit so that when searching for files during `open()`, it returns an error because of a name ambiguity or something like that? If anyone has a clue about this, please tell me so I can test it. Thanks.

Comment: SD has limited amount of rewrites.  You have a bad block on your SD now.

Comment: Side note: you can put at most 31 chars into the filename: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1328

Comment: Ok, I see. I did not know that. but still, as you can see, the filename pattern I've been using has 26 chars. how does it exceeds the max size limit? I'm asking this because all those files on the pastebin link were opened and written just fine, it was after a certain point that it stop working. it is kinda strange , dont you agree?

Comment: Also, I dont think it has to do with max amount of rewrites. this test only made around 3 new files per minute for around an hour. and relatively small files. So, there's no way that's the issue here.

Comment: @thePiGrepper I offered my comment as a side note because you asked about filename size limits. I wasn't suggesting your problem had anything to do with it. Did you try with a new/different SD card?

Comment: Yeah I did and same result.